# What is the meaning of "he's nice, if rather patronizing"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I tried to search for the meaning of "patronizing" in WordWeb Pro. There is an example in the dictionary:

> he's nice, if rather patronizing.

Now the "if rather" portion is confusing me. In my mother tongue (*Bengali*), it is not making any sense. So somebody please explain me the meaning.

Comment: *If rather* isn't a single thing.  You can divide the sentence up like this: [ He's nice, ] if [ rather patronizing ].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, the sentence is equivalent to:

> He is nice, ***even though he is also*** rather patronizing.

Comment: What I find interesting about this sentence is that I can't see the logical sense in it. I wouldn't say that someone who was *patronizing* was also *nice*. I get that that's not really what the question is about, but I think it's a strange sentence nonetheless. +1 :)

Comment: It could mean he is normally nice, even thought sometimes he is patronizing. Would this be a little stretched, or does it make sense?

Comment: @WendiKidd: Consider the case of one do-nothing English gentleman from 1910-1930 or so applying it to another. It's not really a standard modern use, but I can see it working at that time.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I definitely see the two qualities as being expressed as equal/simultaneous. "He's only five years old, but he's also rather smart." The child is both 5 as well as smart. In this sentence I see the person being described as both *nice* and *patronizing* simultaneously, which is why it sounds a bit odd to me.

Comment: @WendiKidd - A little extra context could solve the conundrum: _"He's generally nice, even if he can be somewhat patronizing from time to time."_ (That's how I interpreted the meaning of the original.)